# MVC. Активация DropDownList с помощью RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Есть код,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Depatrments", "Выберите Одно")</td>    
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Arr")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("AArmors", "Выберите Другое")</td>
    </tr>         
</table>

@Html.RadioButton("Active", "false", true) No
@Html.RadioButton("Active", "true") Yes
```

Как и где(во вью или контролере) организовать зависимость dropdownlist от radiobutton? В webforms просто генерировался метод у радиокнопок и посредством свойства Enabled осуществлялось управление комбобоксом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если делать в представлении то можно через JQuery:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="type" id="disable" value="1" checked="" type="radio" class="control"> Disable dropdown
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="type" id="enable" value="0" type="radio" class="control"> Enable dropdown
</label>

@Html.DropDownList("Depatrments", "Выберите Одно")
```

Скрипт:

```
$("#Depatrments").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$(".control").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $("#Depatrments").attr("disabled", "disabled").val('');  //#Depatrments - Id списка
    } else {
        $("#Depatrments").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: может что-то не так делаю, но у меня при обоих нажатых radiobutton активен dropdownlist.

Comment: посмотри тут если есть ошибки подправь [ссылка на .net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZXwUhD)

Comment: решил проблему, спасибо.